# MySQL: subquerys OR unions?

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

`I do not explain the logic of the query`, because it is not simple. If I explain in detail - no one will want to read and delve into the essence of the query.

There are two querys. They do their job well. Result: identical. Checked in manual mode, with a pencil on paper (and on a data base).

Which query will less load the server? Or will it only be found out some time after working on a real (production) server?

---

The operation `UNION` veryhard load the server? `What should I look for in the explanations of the querys?`

---

1 q whith + + +

```
select (select count(comid)  from coms join posts on pid=pid_coms where uid_posts=8888 and uid_coms=8888) 

+
(select count(comid)  from frends join posts on sl_frend=uid_posts join coms on pid=pid_coms 
where uid_coms=8888 and m_frend=8888 and ((postacc=1 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=1))) 

+ 
(select count(comid)  from frends join posts on m_frend=uid_posts join coms on pid=pid_coms
where uid_coms=8888 and sl_frend=8888 and ((postacc=1 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=1)))

+
(select count(comid)  from coms join posts on pid_coms=pid where uid_posts != 8888 and uid_coms=8888 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1) CountMyComms;

EXPLAIN
+----+-------------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type   | possible_keys         | key      | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                | NULL | No tables used |
|  5 | SUBQUERY    | coms   | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       | const               |    7 |                |
|  5 | SUBQUERY    | posts  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where    |
|  4 | SUBQUERY    | frends | ref    | m_frend,sl_frend      | sl_frend | 4       | const               |    1 |                |
|  4 | SUBQUERY    | coms   | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       | const               |    7 |                |
|  4 | SUBQUERY    | posts  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where    |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | coms   | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       | const               |    7 |                |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | posts  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where    |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | frends | ref    | m_frend,sl_frend      | sl_frend | 4       | mbs.posts.uid_posts |    1 | Using where    |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | coms   | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       | const               |    7 |                |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | posts  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where    |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

2 q whith unions

```
select count(comid) from (select comid from coms join posts on pid=pid_coms where uid_posts=8888 and uid_coms=8888 

union
select comid from frends join posts on sl_frend=uid_posts join coms on pid=pid_coms 
where uid_coms=8888 and m_frend=8888 and ((postacc=1 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=1)) 

union 
select comid from frends join posts on m_frend=uid_posts join coms on pid=pid_coms 
where uid_coms=8888 and sl_frend=8888 and ((postacc=1 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=2) or (postacc=2 and postcomacc=1)) 

union 
select comid from coms join posts on pid_coms=pid 
where uid_posts != 8888 and uid_coms=8888 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1) a;

EXPLAIN
+----+--------------+----------------+--------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table          | type   | possible_keys         | key      | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                        |
+----+--------------+----------------+--------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | NULL           | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
|  2 | DERIVED      | coms           | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       |                     |    7 |                              |
|  2 | DERIVED      | posts          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where                  |
|  3 | UNION        | coms           | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       |                     |    7 |                              |
|  3 | UNION        | posts          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where                  |
|  3 | UNION        | frends         | ref    | m_frend,sl_frend      | sl_frend | 4       | mbs.posts.uid_posts |    1 | Using where                  |
|  4 | UNION        | frends         | ref    | m_frend,sl_frend      | sl_frend | 4       |                     |    1 |                              |
|  4 | UNION        | coms           | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       |                     |    7 |                              |
|  4 | UNION        | posts          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where                  |
|  5 | UNION        | coms           | ref    | uid_coms,pid_coms     | uid_coms | 4       |                     |    7 |                              |
|  5 | UNION        | posts          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pid,uid_posts | PRIMARY  | 4       | mbs.coms.pid_coms   |    1 | Using where                  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3,4,5> | ALL    | NULL                  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                | NULL |                              |
+----+--------------+----------------+--------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have to use `COUNT(comid)`? Or can you use `COUNT(*)`? (That is, are there any null `comid` values? `COUNT(*)` is slightly faster.  In your second query, are the sets of `comid` values returned by each part of the `UNION` disjoint?  If so, use `UNION ALL`. Again, use `COUNT(*)` if you can.

Comment: no `null`, ok, i use COUNT(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the sum of record counts for a series of different queries of your tables.

The first alternative ... count each query's results, then add them ... will be faster. Why? It has less work to do. Your second alternative has to wrangle a set of `comid` values, and then count them. That takes time.

Use `COUNT(*)` if you can. It's cheaper.  Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` when you can; `UNION` removes duplicates and `UNION ALL` doesn't. Removing duplicates takes time.

The performance of either alternative depends on good choices for indexes for each subquery.

Comment: `duolicates` impossible, indexes present. Run-time of this ( whith any variants: union,  + + +, count(comid), count(*) ) queryS is less 0.08 sec. Tested on about 70 000 - 100 000 records, All is ok. In the future i need to monitor the production server.