# Ungroup query result

Tags: mysql, grouping, union

If both requests return the same data, then they are "grouped" into the union.

```
query1 return X 
query2 return X

query1 union query2 renurn only X

But i need to get
+---+
| X |
| X |
+---+
```

If each request returns unequal data, the result with the `union` will `consist of two lines. This is normal`.

```
mysql> select count(pid) from posts 
where uid_posts=8890 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1 
union
select count(comid) from coms join posts on pid_coms=pid 
where uid_posts!=8890 and uid_coms=8890 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1;
+------------+
| count(pid) |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          2 |
+------------+
```

`I want to achieve this`.

---

But the common query with the union "grouped" these same values.

```
mysql> select count(pid) from posts
where uid_posts=8890 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1 ;
+------------+
| count(pid) |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+


mysql>  select count(comid) from coms join posts on pid_coms=pid 
where uid_posts!=8890 and uid_coms=8890 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1;
+--------------+
| count(comid) |
+--------------+
|            2 |
+--------------+



//thay are "grouped" :( below

mysql> select count(pid) from posts
where uid_posts=8890 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1 
union
select count(comid) from coms join posts on pid_coms=pid 
where uid_posts!=8890 and uid_coms=8890 and postacc=1 and postcomacc=1;
+------------+
| count(pid) |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
```

### How to ungroup these results?

*Or do I need to rework the entire query?*

### STOP! UNION ALL must hepl me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select count(pid)
from posts 
where uid_posts = 8890 and postacc = 1 and postcomacc = 1 
union all
select count(comid)
from coms join
     posts
     on pid_coms = pid 
where uid_posts <> 8890 and uid_coms = 8890 and postacc = 1 and postcomacc = 1
```

I would also add a second column to specify which count goes with which query.

Comment: aha :) I myself understood this while writing the question. about 8 min i cheked flag `resolve`

Comment: I remembered that I was advised here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153802/mysql-subquerys-or-unions